# Continuity for a nonlinear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, nonlinear-analysis

I'd like to check the continuity for the *nonlinear*  functional $T: (C^{0}([0,1],\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}) \rightarrow  (C^{0}([0,1],\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}) $ , with $T(f)(x)=\arctan(f(x))$.

I need to show that for $f_n \rightarrow f$ in infinity norm, then $T(f_n) \rightarrow T(f)$, also in infinity norm.

So, I need to compute $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} | \arctan(f(x))- \arctan(f_k(x))|$, and I want to show it goes to zero, but how can I compute it formally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|arctan (a) -arctan (b)| \leq |a-b|$ by MVT so $Tf_n \to Tf$ uniformly.

Comment: The conclusion is clear, but I don't understand why that inequality comes from the mean value theorem !

Comment: @VoB $arctan (a)-arctan (b)=(a-b) \frac 1 {1+x^{2}}$ for some $x$ between $a$ and $b$. Note that $\frac 1 {1+x^{2}} \leq 1$.

Comment: Perfect, it's clear ! One last question: how am I using continuity in $[0,1]$ here? 
In order to apply MVT I see that $x \mapsto \arctan(x)$ satisfies the hypothesis of MVT. But where can I use the continuity of $f$?

Comment: MVT is applied for arctan on the real line. It has nothing to do with $f$. After you get the inequality you just replace $a$ by $f(x)$ and $b$ by $f(y)$